# Integer powers program Java help needed

Tags: java, integer

So i was getting this program in my book and tested it, it worked fine. I need help though understanding how it excactly works. I know the power of two means for example 2x2x2x2x2x2x2x2x2 = 512. Well, here is the program:

```
// Compute integer powers of 2.
class Power {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int e;
        int result;
        for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            result = 1;
            e = i;
            while(e > 0) {
                result *= 2;
                e--;
            }
            System.out.println("2 to the " + i + " power is " + result);
         }
     }
}
```

So i've learned that result *=2 means: result = result * 2. I don't get how this works. Example, i is now 4. Result = 1 again, e=i, so e is now 4. 4 is higher than 0, so the while loop runs. Then it say's result is result * 2, but that's 1=1 * 2 = 2. But the result should be 16. How does result changes here to 16? Because it is 1 all the time. I don't get it. Also, why the e-- part? I've tried the program with e++, but then it prints result as 1 and after this only 0. Also tried it without e-- or e++ at all, but then it freezes in the dos-prompt. Please note that i am a beginner and this is my first while loop. Any help i would appreciate.

Comment: double twoToPowerOfEight = Math.pow(2, 8)

Comment: @garryp `int  twoToPowerOfEight = 1 << 8;`

Comment: gerryp and Luu, OP is a learner and he just wants to understand the program. He does not need alternate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using nested loops. That is, a `while` loop inside a `for` loop. This means that for every iteration of `for` loop, `while` loop will execute until it's condition becomes false.

Now coming to your questions, for first iteration of `for`, i = 0. Which means that e = 0, which in-turn means that `while` loop will not execute. So, result is 1 here, which is logical since any n^0 = 1.

For second iteration of `for`, i = 1. Which means that e = 1. Here, `while` loop will run for 1 iteration. It will make result = 2 (result *= 2). So, result is 2 because 2^1 = 2.

Below is the dry-run table.

---

```
for  i    while    e    result
loop      loop
1    0    1        0    1  
2    1    1        1    2
3    2    1        2    2
     1    2        1    4
4    3    1        3    2
     2    2        2    4
     1    3        1    8
```

and so on. This table seems ugly, but it will give you a hint.

> How does result changes here to 16? Because it is 1 all the time.

Result is **only** initialized with 1, but it's value is multiplied each time `while` loop executes.

> I've tried the program with e++, but then it prints result as 1 and
>   after this only 0.

If you put `e++` instead of `e--`, this loop will run until e overflows. But as soon value of e reaches 33, result will become 0 due to multiplication. And after that, it will remain 0.

> Also tried it without e-- or e++ at all, but then it freezes in the
>   dos-prompt.

It means that your condition of while loop will never become false, and hence, it will be an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(e > 0) {
    result * = 2;
    e--;
}
```

this loop executes untill the e becomes zero.
so in first loop

`result = 1 * 2;`

in second loop

`result = result * 2;` means `result = 2 * 2`

likewise.

Comment: Oh, i get it now, i forgot that the while loop keeps running until its false. I made the mistake of thinking that after 1 while loop run it retuns to the for loop, oops, stupid of me :( Thanks!

Comment: its ok .. I am glad it helped. You can now close this question by accepting this answer :)